# Where are these HTML elements created in the Joomla code?

Tags: html, css, joomla, virtuemart

I'm working on a site for a client, and I've never used Joomla before.  I keep seeing elements in the HTML, that I can't find in the code.  It's Joomla with Virtuemart and the bt_bazaar template.

For example, at the top of the page there's a div with the class `bt_toolbar`.  When I search the entire public root of the site, it only turns up a match inside CSS, and this line from `bt_bazaar/helpers/bt_helpers.php`:

```
$this->bt_toolbar = '<jdoc:include type="modules" name="toolbar" style="BTxhtml" />';
```

Where is this toolbar?  How do I find other module types in the code?  Where is the class name bt_toolbar set?

Thanks,
Frankie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a Joomla Module.

You can find the joomla modules under

```
public_html/modules/mod_modulename.
```

here your module name is toolbar but this name may not be the module name (we can have option to use other names and same name).This name stands the position of the module.

go to admin side and in the module manager you can find a module name with toolbar position name.

```
eg: mod_somename.
Then go to front end modules/mod_somename/tmpl/default.php
```

This is the HTML out put of the module.
If you not found the same module on the above path or you changed the file not effecting it.
It may be overrided.
Then you can find the module at

```
public_html/templates/your_tmplate_name/html/mod_somename
```

it depends upon joomla version too.

Hope This will help you...

Comment: Thanks.  This helps narrow down my search.  Is there any regex (I can make it if you describe it) that I could use to find the mapping?

Comment: It turns out, the template prefixes all module positions with 'bt_', which is why I couldn't find the IDs in the code.  Darn dynamic html :-p

Answer (score 1):

BTxhtml  looks like module chrome so look in the modules.php file of your template and see if it is there.

Also name=  tells you the name of the position the module is assigned to, so if you go to the module manager and filter on position toolbar you should find it.